# Best way to save many different objects to Core Data

Tags: swift, performance, dictionary, optimization, core-data

I finished my first app this weekend (*thanks to you Stack Overflow users!*) and I'm currently in the midst of optimizing the code. I already fixed most of the duplicates and un-safe practices but this one is getting me stuck.

Here is how I save all the informations I need for a given cryptocurrency to Core Data when the user adds it to his wallet:

```
if addedCrypto == "Augur REP" {
    if CoreDataHandler.saveObject(name: "Augur", code: "augur", symbol: "REP", placeholder: "REP Amount", amount: "0.00000000", amountValue: "0.0") {
        for _ in CoreDataHandler.fetchObject()! {
        }
    }
}
```

This is pretty handy for one crypto, but my app supports 25 of them. Currently the above lines are duplicated 24 more times in my code, once for each different crypto.

I thought about using a dictionary where I could save `Augur REP` as a `key` and then `(name: "Augur", code: "augur", ...")` as a `value` but I couldn't figure out how to properly to do it..

What could be the solution here?

EDIT: Here is the `saveObject(...)` method:

```
class func saveObject(name:String, code:String, symbol:String, placeholder:String, amount:String, amountValue:String) -> Bool {
    let context = getContext()
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "CryptosMO", in: context)
    let managedObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

    managedObject.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
    managedObject.setValue(code, forKey: "code")
    managedObject.setValue(symbol, forKey: "symbol")
    managedObject.setValue(placeholder, forKey: "placeholder")
    managedObject.setValue(amount, forKey: "amount")
    managedObject.setValue(amountValue, forKey: "amountValue")

    do {
        try context.save()
        return true
    } catch {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: How is your  `saveObject` implemented?

Comment: @Sweeper Like this: `class func saveObject(name:String, code:String, symbol:String, placeholder:String, amount:String, amountValue:String) -> Bool {...}`

Comment: Can you show the body of that method? What I mean is that you are creating some kind of `NSManagedObject` in that method right? Why not just use the `NSManagedObject` subclass as the value type of the dictionary?

Comment: I added the method's code to the question. How would the dictionary look like in that case? I didn't think about that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should create a type alias for a tuple type that stores these information:

```
typealias CryptosMOInfo = (name:String, code:String, symbol:String, placeholder:String, amount:String, amountValue:String)
```

And then you can just create a dictionary like this:

```
let cryptosDictionary: [String, CryptosMOInfo] = [
    "Augur REP": (name: "Augur", code: "augur", symbol: "REP", placeholder: "REP Amount", amount: "0.00000000", amountValue: "0.0"),
    // ...
]
```

The signature of the `saveObject` method can be changed to this:

```
static func saveOject(cryptosInfo: CryptosMOInfo) -> Bool
```

Just remember to access `cryptosInfo`:

```
managedObject.setValue(cryptosInfo.name, forKey: "name")
managedObject.setValue(cryptosInfo.code, forKey: "code")
managedObject.setValue(cryptosInfo.symbol, forKey: "symbol")
managedObject.setValue(cryptosInfo.placeholder, forKey: "placeholder")
managedObject.setValue(cryptosInfo.amount, forKey: "amount")
managedObject.setValue(cryptosInfo.amountValue, forKey: "amountValue")
```

If you don't like the type alias, you can change it into a `struct` as well.

Comment: This looks like the perfect solution! The `dictionary` and the `saveObject` method are not in the same file nor class tho. Can I use it like this safely if I declare the `typealias` in `CryptoPickerViewController` ? `saveObject(cryptosInfo: CryptoPickerViewController.CryptosMOInfo)`

Comment: Why not declare the type alias at the global level? i.e. outside any class. This way it is visible to every bit of your code. @martin

Comment: Oh you're right it works, I'm not familiar with `typealias` yet! Thanks a lot Sweeper

Answer (score 0):

Why not work with the managed object subclass directly? 
Create a new instance when a new crypto is added and then save all aded/updated objects at once.

```
if addedCrypto == "Augur REP" {
  let crypto = CryptosMO(context: CoreDataHandler.getContext())
  crypto.name = "Augur"
  crypto.code = "augur"
  // and so on
}
```

Since this code seems to be the same you could create factory methods in for each crypto you support to make the code easier to read.

```
if addedCrypto == "Augur REP" {
  _ = CryptoFactory.createAugur()
}

class CryptoFacory {
  static func CreateAugur() -> CryptoMO {
     return create(name: "Augur", code: "augur",...
  }
  //... other crypto factory methods

  private static create(name: String, code: String,...) -> CryptoMO {
    let crypto = CryptosMO(context: CoreDataHandler.getContext())
    crypto.name = name
    crypto.code = code
    //...
    return crypto
  }
```

Then the save method in CoreDataHandler would not need any arguments since the crypto instance is already in the managed object context. So it would simply be

```
func save() -> Bool {
  let context = getContext()
  do {
    try context.save()
    return true
  } catch {
    return false
  }
}
```